# How to insert result of forEach into html?

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I am iterating over with forEach and I need to add what is output to the console in html using template strings. How can i do this?

```js
const postCategories = arr[index].category;
const postCategory = postCategories.forEach(category => {
  console.log(category.name);
});

const article = `<article class="news">
<div class="news-taxonomy">
      <span>//Here I need to enter the name of the category</span>
</div>
</article>`;
```

Comment: forEach returns `undefined` ... always ... plus, you don't do anything inside the callback anyway, except output something to the console ... perhaps you want `map`

Comment: so i am asking how can i display category name inside template strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` returns `undefined`, `.map` will return to you a result you're after.

I'm going to assume that each category contains at least a `name` key...
Additionally, I'm assuming you want to insert the result of that *at the end* of all the iterations

```
const postCategories = arr[index].category;
const postCategory = postCategories.map(category => {
  return `<div>${category.name}</div>`;
});

const article = `
  <article class="news">
    <div class="news-taxonomy">
        ${postCategory}
    </div>
  </article>
`;
```

**Note:** This is my preferred format for multiline strings using "`` ` ` ``.

The output would be something like this:

```
<article class="news">
  <div class="news-taxonomy">
      <div>Category 1</div>
      <div>Second Category</div>
      <div>Category 3</div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to inject in the `body` with `insertAdjacentHTML`.

`beforeend` means just before the `body` end tag.

```js
const postCategories = ['one', 'two', 'three']
const postCategory = postCategories.forEach(category => {
  const template = `<article class="news">
    <div class="news-taxonomy">
      <span>${category}</span>
    </div>
  </article>`
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template)
});
```